# Scraping historical data from Yahoo Finance with Python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

as some of you probably know by now, it seems that Yahoo! Finance has discontinued its API for stock market data. While I am aware of the existence of the `fix-yahoo-finance` solution, I was trying to implement a more stable solution to my code by directly scraping historical data from Yahoo.

So here is what I have for the moment:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=345423600&period2=1495922400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup
print(soup.prettify())
```

To get the data from Yahoo table I can do:

```
c=soup.find_all('tbody')
print(c)
```

My question is, how do I turn "c" into a nicer dataframe? Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that Pandas can import Yahoo finance data (watch the pandas version!), which gives you a nice data frame?

Comment: perfectly aware of that, but my work depends on this code and I am aware that Yahoo has the legitimacy to prevent Pandas from downloading data at any time, exactly as they discontinued their API, this is why I am looking for a safer solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wrote this to get historical data from YF directly from the download csv link. It needs to make two requests, one to get the cookie and the crumb and another one to get the data. It returns a pandas dataframe

```
import re
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import requests
import pandas as pd


class YahooFinanceHistory:
    timeout = 2
    crumb_link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/history?p={0}'
    crumble_regex = r'CrumbStore":{"crumb":"(.*?)"}'
    quote_link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{quote}?period1={dfrom}&period2={dto}&interval=1d&events=history&crumb={crumb}'

    def __init__(self, symbol, days_back=7):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.dt = timedelta(days=days_back)

    def get_crumb(self):
        response = self.session.get(self.crumb_link.format(self.symbol), timeout=self.timeout)
        response.raise_for_status()
        match = re.search(self.crumble_regex, response.text)
        if not match:
            raise ValueError('Could not get crumb from Yahoo Finance')
        else:
            self.crumb = match.group(1)

    def get_quote(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'crumb') or len(self.session.cookies) == 0:
            self.get_crumb()
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        dateto = int(now.timestamp())
        datefrom = int((now - self.dt).timestamp())
        url = self.quote_link.format(quote=self.symbol, dfrom=datefrom, dto=dateto, crumb=self.crumb)
        response = self.session.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), parse_dates=['Date'])
```

You can use it like this:

```
df = YahooFinanceHistory('AAPL', days_back=30).get_quote()
```

Comment: I have just realized what a great answer this is, thanks a lot for it

Comment: @Mike D How did you come up with that quote_link ? :p

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the python library **yfinance** and **yahoofinancials**.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
```

Choose the company stock ticker, eg. 'AAPL'.

```
df = yf.download('AAPL')
```

This will store historical stock data to the dataframe df.